# How create a many2one field in with webclient

Tags: odoo

I created a many2one field other the web client.

1. setting --> Technical --> Database Structure --> Models
2. add 3 field to the model (x_ebene1,x_ebene2,x_ebene3) each is a char field
3. setting --> technical --> Database Structure --> fields --> create --> many2one
4. setting --> technical --> user interface --> view --> in the right view insert

When I edit the field, the dropdown shows every time "Administrator". What I need is the value `x_ebene1,x_ebene2` in my dropdown field.

Comment: Do you mean you want the names of the fields to be shown in the dropdown? Please explain more what exactly you want.

Comment: That's right. I want to show in my dropdown the values of my fields like "x_ebene1 - x_ebene2". I found out, that I have to use a field named "x_name" to show the value of name in my dropdown. I also found out, that I can define the value there are shown in the dropdown with _rec_name or name_get(). But I don't know there I have to do this.

Comment: why do you want to show field names in the dropdown. For which model do you want this. What is your purpose behind it. In which dropdown you want to show the values. Not getting you exact requirement.

Comment: The model I create on my self.
I need a dropdown field, where I can add more lines. That's why I choose a many2one field. The model behind the field need 3 fields.

Comment: The model I create on my self.
At the end I need a dropdown field there I can select a category with 3 levels. That's why I choose a many2one field. The model behind the field need 3 fields. Every field is one level. Later this fields will be also many2one field, but this is not so difficulty. 
Examble:
when I add a new line in my dropdown, should looks like:
Level1: vehicle
Level2: cars
Level3: oldtimer
in my dropdown I only see the value of Level1. in this examble: vehicle
I want to see "vehicle - cars - oldtimer"

Comment: http://dirtyhandsphp.blogspot.de/2014/09/odooopenerp-recname-and-nameget.html
here is the URL where I get my informations, but where must I put the code